# SymmetricDS File Synchronization on android

Tags: android, file, synchronization, symmetricds

I'm using symmetricDS for sync my app db(sqlite) and server database(SQLServer) and i try syncing files between my app and server but after create file in target directory in server side, new record create on outgoing batch by "New" status and never change to "OK" status.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJkUk.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code. Have you got logs or anything?

Comment: I tried this code: [http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html-single/user-guide.html#filesync-examples](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html-single/user-guide.html#filesync-examples)

Comment: Also i tried this : http://www.jumpmind.com/blog/file-sync-made-easy

Answer (score 1):

SymmetricDS version 3.8 will include Android file sync, and will be released in about a month. http://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view.php?id=2687